# database.find{} problems with nedb in node.js-express

Tags: nedb

I am new with nedb in node.js

I have this database line

```
{"r":{"Processing_Equipment":"\"Diffusion Furnaces & Accessories\"","ID":"\"9102867\"","Model":"\"VTP 1500\"","Vintage":"\"1995\""},"searchValue":"search","_id":"oQXt8iTDbAhlOsxm"}
```

If I query 
`database.find{} either database.find{searchValue: "search"}` ... etc everything goes fine.

But querying

```
database.find{{"r":{ID:"9102867"}}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log("found from database", data);
});
```

the data[] array is empty.

How can I query what within the r:{} field?
Thanks

Comment: According to their docs, `If no document is found, docs is equal to []`. I'm not familiar with the syntax but whatever you're passing into the `find` (`{"r":{ID:"9102867"}`) doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Rastalamm, thanks. Yes, what I am passing in the find is not correct. What do you guess can be the correct find for the r:{} line of the database?